# Bootstrap and collapse without Accordian

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two anchor's and two div's and I wanted to use collapse function to hide and show the content of div's. It work ok but I have one problem, when I click first anchor it expand but when I click second it show the content of the second one but don't hide the content of first one.

```
<div class="row mobile-options hidden-md hidden-lg">
 <ul>
  <li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#filtr" class="mobile-options-item" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="mr5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i></span> Filtr</a></li>
  <li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#categories" class="mobile-options-item" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="mr5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> Categories</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>


<div id="filtr" class="collapse">
       Filtr content
</div>


<div id="categories" class="collapse">
       Categories content
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/IdbPEK3ROM

I can't use .accordion or .panel because the div's are not next to each other.

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close one div when the other opens - Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971819/close-one-div-when-the-other-opens-bootstrap)

Comment: Does your solution works only in Bootstrap 2.x ? Because I've tried it with Bootstrap 3.x and it don't work. Nothing changes when I added your javascript and `data-collapse-group` to my links. I even change it to the buttons but still no luck.

Comment: It's made for bootstrap 3.x. Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added 2 additional attributes for `a` tags: `data-target` and `data-collapse-group` (custom attribute that specifies which divs must be collapsed).

[**jsFiddle exmpale**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/vKrk5/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mobile-options">
        <ul>
            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#filtr" data-target="#filtr" class="mobile-options-item" data-collapse-group="myDivs"  data-toggle="collapse"><span class="mr5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i></span> Filtr</a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#categories" data-target="#categories" class="mobile-options-item" data-collapse-group="myDivs"  data-toggle="collapse"><span class="mr5"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span> Categories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="filtr" class="collapse">
        <p>Filtr content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="categories" class="collapse">
        <p>Categories content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
        $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
            $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
        });
    });
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/vKrk5/4/)

Comment: Ok, now it works like I needed, thank you. One more thing, it's not so important but it provide better UX: Now when I expand the div #filtr, the view scroll-up to the beginning of the div#filtr, so it works like #top, etc. Is it possible to work like accordian? so the div#filtr will slide down and the a tag stay in the position and the #filtr just show below?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in bootstrap way, but I will be doing something like this

First I will hide all `collapse` div's, Then I will show whatever div I need to show based on the click event

```
$(function(){
  $('.mobile-options-item').click(function(){
    $('.collapse').hide();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).show();
    });
})
```

Link: http://www.bootply.com/pVfjihcVYE

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it don't work in 100% correct. Yes, it hide one `.mobile-options-item` and show second one but you can't just close already expanded item by clicking on link. Check you bootply link.