# Bootstrap Collapse Button How to prevent two collapse showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that goes like this:

```
        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#about" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">About</a> 

        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#contact" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Contact</a>

        <div class="collapse" id="about">
            <div class="well">
            about
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="contact">
            <div class="well">
            contact us
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I click the two buttons, two collapse boxes will show up. Is there a way to only show one collapse at a time let say if I click "About" button the "Contact" collapse will close if it is open and then if I click "Contact" button again the "About" collapse box will close.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding some jquery  code

Comment: ok let me try :) thank you

Comment: the same result, I believe data-target="#id" is for button, I forgot to mention I am using link and I already have  href="#id". .

Comment: you can trigger a jquery function on each button click which has the code if ($('#yourElement').css('display') != 'none')
{
   $('#yourElement').css('display','none')
} try trigering function on click event of each button

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, all I did was added the below within the head tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>

<<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).on('load', function() {
$("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
        $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
    });
});
});//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to the post below :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971819/close-one-div-when-the-other-opens-bootstrap