# How to hide all Bootstrap collapse containers on click with animation before showing next container?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page that has multiple  elements with each containing one or more buttons that triggers a collapsible Bootstrap container. I used the code below, taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973965/2063351) to set it up so that when the user clicks a button, any open container closes and the target opens.

```
$("[data-collapse-group='collapseGroups']").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("[data-collapse-group='collapseGroups']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
        $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
    });
});
```

It works okay, but I would really like for the container that is currently open to animate closed, similar to how it folds upwards if you clicked on the same open element to collapse it. Then, once the current element is closed the target container would open.

Here's a sample of my HTML:

```
<div class="myList">
    <div class="myListRow">
        <div class="myListHeader">
            <span class="myHeader">Title1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" data-collapse-group="collapseGroups" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">Button1</button>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse1" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="well">
                <span>Well Contents</span>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a bunch of buttons and collapsible elements, and the IDs/data-targets for each are dynamically generated (collapse1, collapse57, etc).

Is it possible to get the open container to close gracefully as if it were being collapsed by clicking on it before the target container starts opening?

Thanks.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly it sounds like you want more of an accordion type function. Have you reviewed [Bootstrap > Collapse > Accordion Example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) that may help. You could generate each list item ID sequentially.

Comment: @jameswassinger - Yes, I've reviewed and actually tried to implement the accordion example, but I ran into issues since I can't contain each section, identified by `<div class="myList">`, in the same panel. Using the accordion also caused my buttons to appear to want to `display: block` and I want them to display horizontally side by side with the containers appearing below. Also, the accordion doesn't behave quite like I want...it animates quickly on closing and opening containers. I want the open container to close slowly as if it was collapsing itself, then animate open the target container